# Expression/word for "the one who is in charge of something"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am designing a website form and, on this form, there is a field where I want the user to enter the e-mail of an employee designated by him to be in charge of/responsible for something.

How should I label this field? A single word/term is preferable.

```
<...> E-mail:
 ______________
|______________|
```

Comment: The answer will probably depend on what the designated person is responsible for.

Comment: "Assigned to"  (or "Delegated to").

Comment: @Nathaniel, let's say he could be responsible for anything, from something VERY important, to the least important thing someone could be responsible for on that context. Is there a term that I could use that would just denote the act of having the responsibility (i.e being guilty if things goes wrong, receiving compliments if it all goes well) on something but does not imply any hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possibilities and, **depending on context**, you might choose one or another.

- **"man in charge"**
- **"administrator"**
- **"controller"**
- **"supervisor"**

Comment: Thank you. Man in charge seems to be just right for what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Typically, one would call this type of employee a [*manager*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/manager), which Dictionary.com says is:

> A person who has control or direction of an institution, business, etc., or of a part, division, or phase of it.

Either a sales manager, product manager, team manager, etc.  You could also use the term *lead*, as in application lead, or tech lead.

Comment: Supposing the employee is "not important", i.e his position/wage is mediocre, would you STILL use this term (`manager`)

Answer (score 0):

**Team Leader**

This implies that

- This person is responsible for a certain area
- They have someone they report to (ie. a manager)

The team leader doesn't have to be an actual person with that role. Often if you ask for the team leader you'll get sent to the manager who might then create a team. Or in other cases whoever is "in charge" might take responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

**Proxy** or **surrogate**.

If you do not want to imply a hierarchy, as words like *manager*, *supervisor*, and *leader* do, then words like these might work.

Proxy:

> power or authority that is given to allow a person to act for someone else ([MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proxy))

Surrogate:

> one that serves as a substitute ([MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/surrogate))

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, never used those terms before. Proxy looks good.

Comment: Sounds to me as though you need them to insert the job-title eg. *Sales Manager, Head of IT, Cleaning supervisor.*

Answer (score 0):

I would use the word Delegate. 
noun - a person designated to act for or represent another or others; deputy; representative, as in a political convention.

In this use, it is generally pronounced del-uh-git as opposed to the verb form that is pronounced del-uh-gayt.